# Upgrading Sony Xperia E to Android 4.3

Tags: cyanogenmod, updates, rom-flashing

I have the Sony Xperia E and want to use a Bluetooth Smart/Bluetooth Low Energy Heart Rate Monitor with it.

Unfortunately this requires Android 4.3 and Sony stopped upgrading it at Android 4.1.1

Is it possible to install a later version on Android on this phone? I looked at the Cyanogen website (http://download.cyanogenmod.org/) but couldn't see the Sony Xperia E listed, the phones product number is C1505.

I'm happy to root the phone, flash it etc as long as I have good instructions to follow.

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note**: Partial answer to address Cyanogenmod unavailability.

---

The reason why you couldn't find your device [here](https://download.cyanogenmod.org/) is because Cyanogenmod(CM) didn't port it on your device model for some reason. To be precise, there is no official CM for your device. That said there are some unofficial custom ROMs (including CM) available for your device.

<sub>(Click [here](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/blog/a-note-on-unofficial-ports-and-how-to-get-it-right) to know the difference between official and unofficial CM.)</sub>

According to a user in this [link](http://www.android-hilfe.de/root-custom-roms-modding-fuer-sony-xperia-e/571836-cutom-rom-fuer-sony-xperia-e-c1505-mit-android-4-2-4-4-a.html), the official XDA thread for your device is [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-j-e/general/xperia-e-official-thread-roms-mods-root-t2535522), and the relevant ROMs are:

> CM11 (4.4.4): http://forum.xda-developers.com/xper...-11-0-t2648316
>
> AOKP (4.4.4): http://forum.xda-developers.com/xper...4-4-4-t2795440
>
> CarbonRom (4.4.2): http://forum.xda-developers.com/xper...icm11-t2783757

<sub>(The instructions to flash are mentioned in the corresponding links. Otherwise, you may go to the official XDA thread.)</sub>

---

<sub>**Be cautioned to check the "Status:Stable" for any unofficial ROM that you want to flash.**</sub>

Comment: Unfortunately I won't be trying the OS upgrade as the phone hardware only supports Bluetooth 2.1+EDR (see page 9 here http://www-support-downloads.sonymobile.com/c1505/whitepaper_EN_c1505_xperia_e.pdf) Thanks for the advice about doing the software upgrade, hopefully it will be useful for someone else!

Comment: Also Sony never open sourced this phone's drivers, so the video camera doesn't work, for example.